# ffmpeg extracted frames with zero indexed filename

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, filenames

I'm using this command to extract all the frames from a video

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -qscale:v 2 -vf "transpose=2" "<path>\%10d.jpg"
```

and I obtain all the jpg starting from 0000000001.jpg

How can I make it start from 0000000000.jpg?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the image2 muxer's start_number option

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -qscale:v 2 -vf "transpose=2" -start_number 0 "<path>\%10d.jpg"
```

Comment: -start_number 0 worked!